# Why the spectrum of an even function is real-only?

Tags: signal-processing

I am referering to section $8.5 of Lyons' DSP book:
[[Understanding Digital Signal Processing, 2nd, Richard G. Lyons, 2005]](https://www.pearson.com/us/higher-education/product/Lyons-Understanding-Digital-Signal-Processing-2nd-Edition/9780131089891.html)

There is an [online version](https://books.google.com/books?id=UBU7Y2tpwWUC&pg=PT560&lpg=PT560&dq=The%20directions%20in%20which%20the%20spectral%20impulses%20are%20pointing%20merely%20indicate%20the%20relative%20phases%20of%20the%20spectral%20components.%20The%20amplitude%20of%20those%20spectral%20impulses%20are%201/2.&source=bl&ots=kamDdwA97W&sig=r3_NwlUk8b6FnbY8zdQ6vc5-Ol8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj6vcCz6brVAhUO7mMKHdnTDOgQ6AEILTAB#v=onepage&q&f=false).

And here is the screen shot of the specific part:

[image]

I just too dumb to get the connection between the evenness/oddness of the function and the real-only/imagnary-only of their spectrum from the text...

Thanks a lot,

/bruin

Comment: This would a better fit for [dsp.stackexchange.com](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/) (where [Richard Lyons](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/users/15391/richard-lyons) is actually active).

Comment: A similar question has been asked on math.stackexchange.
You can find the [question complete with answers here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/184332).

Comment: Thanks a lot for both of you!

Answer (score 0):

I read an explanation from a book, roughly, it says that:

1. The FT of even functions are also even; The FT of odd functions are also odd.
2. The real part of the FT of a real function is even; The imaginary part of the FT of a real function is odd.

So the Fourier Transform F(ω) of a *real and even* function f(x) must satisfy both:

1. Because f(x) is even: F(ω) is even (for both real and imaginary parts)
2. Because f(x) is real: the real part of F(ω) is even, and the imaginary part is odd

Now for the imaginary part of F(ω) to be both even and odd, it must be zero, thus F(ω) is real-only.

Answer (score -1):

It's due to [Euler's formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) applying to all the FTs basis functions/vectors, and how two definitions fit two trig identities:

Symmetric or even functions:

cos(x) = cos(-x)

Anti-symmetric or odd function:

sin(x) = -sin(-x)

For all x.

Note also that the sine and cosine functions are orthogonal, thus any signal composed of one set will have zero content of the other.